# Changing an existing Region's type in GemFire/Geode

Tags: gemfire, geode

Once a Region is created in Geode, say as a `PARTITION` type, is it possible to change the type to something else, such as `PARTITION_PERSISTENT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@juanramos** is correct. You really only have the ability to alter (modify) a Region based on the configuration exposed in the `AttributesMutator` interface (see [Javadoc](https://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/cache/AttributesMutator.html)).

Programmatically, this would be acquired with:

```java
AttributesMutator attributesMutator = region.getAttributesMutator();

// alter the Region using the AttributesMutator, such as by adding a new CacheListener
```

In fact this is exactly how the [`alter region` command](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/114/tools_modules/gfsh/command-pages/alter.html#topic_E74ED23CB60342538B2175C326E7D758) in *Gfsh* was implemented (i.e. by using a `Function` to distribute the operation of altering/modifying the *Region* using the *Region's* `AttributesMutator` across the cluster of nodes hosting the *Region*).

So, as **Juan** described, you can:

1. [Export Data](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/114/tools_modules/gfsh/command-pages/export.html#topic_263B70069BFC4A7185F86B3272011734) from the Region
2. Then, [destroy the Region](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/114/tools_modules/gfsh/command-pages/destroy.html#topic_BEDACECF4599407794ACBC0E56B30F65)
3. Next, [re-create the Region](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/114/tools_modules/gfsh/command-pages/create.html#topic_54B0985FEC5241CA9D26B0CE0A5EA863) with the desired `DataPolicy` (e.g. `PARTITION_PERSISTENT`)
4. Finally, [Import Data](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/114/tools_modules/gfsh/command-pages/import.html#topic_jw2_2ld_2l) back into the re-created Region.

Of course, if you do not have any data, then you can simply destroy and recreate the Region as well.

***Spring Boot for Apache Geode*** makes [data handling](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/#geode-data-using) (e.g. export and import) very simple to do, and can even be performed on an application restart (particularly during development time).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is not possible out of the box... You can, however, use the [`gfsh export data`](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/114/tools_modules/gfsh/command-pages/export.html#topic_263B70069BFC4A7185F86B3272011734) command to export the current region data, destroy the `region`, create a new one with the correct type, and then use the [`gfsh import data`](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/114/tools_modules/gfsh/command-pages/import.html#import-data) command to re populate the region from the backup.